# The injected managed property is null

Tags: nullpointerexception, managed-property

I have a JSF managed bean to create app dependent User instances (UserFactory interface implementor). I'd like to use this factory in the EJB container. The app throws a NullPointerException because the value of the UserWithRolesDAL.userFactory is null. But why?

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserWithRolesSER
{
  @Inject
  private UserWithRolesBUS userBUS;

  ... 
}

@Dependent
class UserWithRolesBUS
{
  @Inject
  private UserWithRolesDAL userDAL;

  ... 
}

@Dependent
class UserWithRolesDAL
{
  @ManagedProperty( value = "#{userFactory}" )
  private UserFactory userFactory;

  ... 
}

public interface UserFactory
{
  public UserWithRoles createUser();
}

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
@Named( value = "userFactory" )
public class XUserFactory implements UserFactory
{
  ...
}
```